# Preferred way of mocking Redshift and S3 locally

Tags: mocking, airflow, localstack

##### Problem

I've an **[Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/)** pipeline that I'd like to run locally, which does the following:

1. Downloads tables from **Redshift** to a **S3** bucket (basically [`RedshiftToS3Operator`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/stable/_api/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/transfers/redshift_to_s3/index.html?highlight=redshifttos3operator#airflow.providers.amazon.aws.transfers.redshift_to_s3.RedshiftToS3Operator))
2. Copies the tables from the **S3** bucket to another **Redshift** (basically [`S3ToRedshiftOperator`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/stable/_api/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/transfers/s3_to_redshift/index.html?highlight=s3toredshiftoperator#airflow.providers.amazon.aws.transfers.s3_to_redshift.S3ToRedshiftOperator))

##### Question

Would it be possible to use QA Redshift, then copy those files to locally mocked S3 with LocalStack and finally use a mocked PosgreSQL for the second Redshift? Would this approach have more pros than cons?

**Note**: I'm not thinking of mocking Redshift locally with LocalStack, since apparently

> the redshift service only mocks the redshift management endpoints (create cluster, etc...) and not the actual query engine. [SO 1st comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53901963/18466829)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [redshift-fake-driver](https://github.com/opt-tech/redshift-fake-driver) project, which allows you to simulate Redshift on top of PostgreSQL by translating and implementing certain Redshift-specific commands on the fly in the JDBC database driver itself, mainly `UNLOAD` and `COPY` - the commands to load Redshift tables to and from S3 (I use LocalStack's S3).

You can interface with the JDBC driver from Python using the [JayDeBeApi](https://pypi.org/project/JayDeBeApi/) Python package, this is how I use it. It works quite nicely, simulating enough of Redshift's features locally, and combined with LocalStack S3, you can build fully local Redshift and S3 pipelines.